# Require help in showing thumbnails on folders in Gallery view

Tags: sharepoint-online, folder, thumbnail, gallery-view

I have created a gallery view. All the folders are showing a simple folder icon. I want to show unique pictures as thumbnails instead of a simple folder icon. Kindly help[image: folders images]

Comment: You can customize the card design in "Advance mode" using "Format current view" option/JSON view formatting and add `img` element in card JSON for showing image as thumbnail.